# How to execute oracle stored procedure from windows script file?

Tags: stored-procedures, sqlplus, wsh, jscript

Little help needed:

```
var oShell_1 = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell");
    oShell_1.run ("cmd /c CD C:\\ && sqlplus.exe user/pass@DATABASE && execute proc() /c;", 2 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true /* bWaitOnReturn */);
```

Does not work =(. Also I want window stay opened. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the case: `oShell_1.run(...)` should be `oShell_1.Run(...)`. `2` as "intWindowStyle" displays the window minimized, normally `1` is used when launching an application.

Also I think comments within arguments might be illegal.